# Put array like [1,3] give the error 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid destructuring assignment target'

Tags: javascript, arrays, function

I write a bubble sort function to arrange numbers in the array, but when I put array like [1,3] ,vscode and chrome give me the

> Identifier expected.javascript  OR
> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid destructuring assignment target

here is the full code

```js
function bubbleg(arr) {

  var len = arr.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < len - 1; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < len - 1 - i; j++) {
      if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1]) {
        var temp = arr[j];
        arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
        arr[j + 1] = temp;

      }
    }
  }
  return arr;
}

function bubbleg([1, 3]);
```

After make a change, like

```
num= [1,3] function bubbleg(num);
```

Everything is good, but why we can not put the something like bubbleg([1,3])? Is there any books so  when I look it up with some bugs list in it  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not about the `[1, 3]` argument you pass. But how you call the function.

Here is the correct code:

```js
function bubbleg(arr) {

    var len = arr.length;
    for (var i = 0; i < len - 1; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < len - i - 1; j++) {
            if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1]) {
                var temp = arr[j];
                arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
                arr[j + 1] = temp;

            }
        }
    }
    return arr;
} 
        
 console.log(bubbleg( [3,1] ));
```

Comment: yes, without i is ok.but will make the code be excuded little longer

Comment: Yes - it is an optimization technique. I will edit the answer.

Answer (score 3):

remove function keyword in calling your function. `function` is keyword used to **declare** function, not to **call** it.

```js
function bubbleg(arr) {
  var len = arr.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < len - 1; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < len - 1 - i; j++) {
      if (arr[j] > arr[j + 1]) {
        var temp = arr[j];
        arr[j] = arr[j + 1];
        arr[j + 1] = temp;

      }
    }
  }
  return arr;
}
bubbleg([1, 3]);
```

Answer (score 2):

that is because you're not calling the function bubbleg correctly

```
function bubbleg([1,2])
```

should be

```
bubbleg([1,2])
```